# Axiom of choice for choosing a sequence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset X$ with $x_n \neq x_m$ for $n\neq m$. To see this we can argue inductively: choose $x_1$ arbitrarily. If $x_1, \dots, x_n$ Are already chosen there must exist a $x_{n+1} \in X\setminus \{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$ since otherwise $X$ is finite.

But why can we actually argue like this? This is just an example but there are many situations were these kind of argumentation is used. It’s not classical induction, since we don’t verify that a statement $A(n)$ is true for all $n$. One also chooses all $x_n$ in dependency of each other. So is this something like the axiom of choice?

Comment: Which definition of infinite set are you using?

Comment: A set that is not finite. A finite set is a set for which there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that it has the same cardinality as $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: The principle you are using is called the axiom of dependent choice. It is a consequence of the axiom of choice (but quite a lot weaker).  Google it.

Comment: @RobArthan but what is here the homogenous relation? It’s not $\neq$ since then we could end up with the sequence $x_{2n}=a$ and $x_{2n+1}=b$.

Comment: Do you include zero in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @zkutch I started here with 1 but it shouldn’t matter right?

Comment: You can apply the "total homogeneous relation" statement of DC here for example to the set of all *finite* sequences of *distinct* elements of $X$, with the relation "$\mathbf x R \mathbf y$ if the sequence $\mathbf y$ extends the sequence $\mathbf x$ by one element". The fact that you're not verifying a statement isn't really what makes it require choice, though - generally recursively defining a sequence doesn't need choice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem. It's just when you have to make a choice at each stage of the recursion that you need something like DC.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Comment: If $0$ is not in Your $\mathbb{N}$, then $\emptyset$ becomes infinite also, accordingly to your definition in comment.